# how to identify whether user has disable wifi control access from special app access in Android 9?

Tags: android, wifi, android-9.0-pie

In android 9, automatic WiFi enablement by app can be revoked using manual setting as mentioned (Settings > Apps & notifications > Special app access > Wi-Fi control.) [here](https://source.android.com/setup/start/p-release-notes#wi-fi_permission_updates). Is there way to identify if user has disabled this option manually since I want to handle this scenario as it shows pop up when app tries to enable WiFi using wifimanager.setEnable(true);

Answer (score 1):

Using usual permission check:

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, 
    Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
```

Comment: this always returns "true" even if wifi control setting is manually disable via (Settings > Apps & notifications > Special app access > Wi-Fi control.)

Comment: @AmolDesai could you find a solution? I'm struggling with the same problem.

Comment: You can bet on 'SecurityException' while calling wifimanager#setWifiEnable(true);